# Why my call map function is hide in the count nodeList but it is visible in return output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios, use-effect

This will be a complex sample cause my codes is like a lot...

So basically I just direct to my point. My problem is that I don't know why my list map function is not includes the output function of return when I'm trying to get the `document.querySelectorAll()` of all the items. Basically something like this.

```
            <div className='gallery' style={ ispost ? { display:'none' } : {display:"block"}}>
                {mainList.map((elem,idx) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="gallery-container" key={idx}>
                            <div className="l">
                                <div className="l-box">
                                    <div className="text">
                                        <div className="hide">
                                            <h2> Onigsahima Tokyo </h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="hide">
                                        <div className="color-sample">
                                            <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="r">
                                <div className="r-box">
                                    <div className="hide">
                                        <div className="color-sample">
                                            <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="r-box">
                                    <div className="hide">
                                        <div className="color-sample">
                                            <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="r-box">
                                    <div className="hide">
                                        <div className="color-sample">
                                            <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="r-box">
                                    <div className="hide">
                                        <div className="color-sample">
                                            <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
                <div className="gallery-container" style={ ispost ? { display:'none' } : {display:"inline-grid"}}>
                    <div className="l">
                        <div className="l-box">
                            <div className="text">
                                <div className="hide">
                                    <h2> Onigsahima Tokyo </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="hide">
                                <div className="color-sample">
                                    <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="r">
                        <div className="r-box">
                            <div className="hide">
                                <div className="color-sample">
                                    <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="r-box">
                            <div className="hide">
                                <div className="color-sample">
                                    <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="r-box">
                            <div className="hide">
                                <div className="color-sample">
                                    <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="r-box">
                            <div className="hide">
                                <div className="color-sample">
                                    <img src={g3} alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
```

And then  I have a `useEffect()` and I'll show all the codes about it..but don't get confused about it just focus on the `querySelectorAll()` cause it is the only thing that affect it all the animation

```
    useEffect(() => {

        gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger,CSSRulePlugin)
        // gsap.registerPlugin(CSSRulePlugin)
        const sections_ = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-container')
        console.log(sections_)
        let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".gallery-container")
        console.log(sections)
        let scrollTween = gsap.to(sections, {
            xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
            ease: "none", // <-- IMPORTANT!
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: ".gallery",
                pin: true,
                scrub: 3,
                end: "+=3000",
                // markers:true
            }
        });

        
        gsap.to(".gallery-container:nth-child(1) .color-sample",{
            y:0,
            ease:"none",
            scrollTrigger:{
                trigger:".gallery-container:nth-child(1)",
                containerAnimation:scrollTween,
                start:"0% 0%",
                end:"10% 6%",
                // markers:{startColor: "orange", endColor: "green"},
                scrub:2,
            }
        })
        const rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(`.r-box:after`)
        const rule2 = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(`.r-box:before`)
        gsap.to([rule,rule2],{
            width:'35%',
            height:'35%',
            background:"yellow",
            delay:3,
            ease:"none",
            scrollTrigger:{
                trigger:`.gallery-container:nth-child(1)`,
                containerAnimation:scrollTween,
                start:"0% 0%",
                end:"10% 6%",
                // markers:true,
                scrub:2,
            }
        })

        gsap.to(`.gallery-container:nth-child(1) .text h2`,{
            y:0,
            // delay:2,
            ease:"none",
            scrollTrigger:{
                trigger:`.gallery-container:nth-child(1)`,
                containerAnimation:scrollTween,
                start:"0% 0%",
                end:"10% 6%",
                // markers:true,
                scrub:2,
            }
        })

        sections.forEach((elem,i) => {
            gsap.to(`.gallery-container:nth-child(${i+2}) .color-sample`,{
                y:0,
                ease:"none",
                scrollTrigger:{
                    trigger:`.gallery-container:nth-child(${i+2})`,
                    containerAnimation:scrollTween,
                    start:"center 50%",
                    end:"center 60%",
                    // markers:true,
                    scrub:2,
                }
            })

            gsap.to(`.gallery-container:nth-child(${i+2}) .text h2`,{
                y:0,
                // delay:2,
                ease:"none",
                scrollTrigger:{
                    trigger:`.gallery-container:nth-child(${i+2})`,
                    containerAnimation:scrollTween,
                    start:"center 50%",
                    end:"center 60%",
                    // markers:true,
                    scrub:2,
                }
            })

            const rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(`.r-box:after`)
            const rule2 = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(`.r-box:before`)
            gsap.to([rule,rule2],{
                width:'35%',
                height:'35%',
                background:"yellow",
                delay:3,
                ease:"none",
                scrollTrigger:{
                    trigger:`.gallery-container:nth-child(${i+2})`,
                    containerAnimation:scrollTween,
                    start:"center 50%",
                    end:"center 60%",
                    // markers:true,
                    scrub:2,
                }
            })

        })


        const arrowsColor = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow.first ion-icon')
        const arrows2Color = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow.second ion-icon')

        var scrollPos = 0 
        window.addEventListener('scroll',() => { 
            if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos) {
                // console.log('Right')
                arrowsColor.forEach(elem => {
                    elem.style.color = 'black'
                })
                arrows2Color.forEach(elem => {
                    elem.style.color = 'yellow'
                })
            } else {
                // console.log('Left')
                arrowsColor.forEach(elem => {
                    elem.style.color = 'yellow'
                })
                arrows2Color.forEach(elem => {
                    elem.style.color = 'black'
                })
            }
            scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top
        })

    },[])
```

I don't know if this is easiest way to explain it but this is the best I can..
**Note that** mainList is a `useState` so I'll have something like this in my codes
when I am pushing the items in `setMainList`

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:7777/gallery')
        .then(res => {
                let del = []
                res.data.map((elem,i) => {
                    console.log(i)
                    setMainList([...mainList,elem]) 
                })
            })
    },[])
```

Yes it works but why the `document.querySelectorAll` don't detect if there is a new element that I pop in that `mainList.map` function? I don't understand why..It shouldn't be this kind of way. I always do this but never encounter this bug..
Note that `mainList.map()` is like visible but it is not include in that `querySelectorlAll`
Please help badly need it to get this thing done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `useEffect` callback runs only once since you haven't added any dependencies. If you want the callback to be invoked whenever `mainList` changes, add `mainList` to the `useEffect` dependency list like so

```
useEffect(() => {
  //...
}, [mainList])
```

Be careful though! You should use the return callback to remove any listeners or subscriptions you've set up.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //...
  
  function onScroll() {
    //...
  }
  window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)

  return () => {
    // remove listeners
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
  }
}, [mainList])
```

I don't know how `gsap` works, but you might also want to "deregister" the plugin in the tear-down callback, or just use a different `useEffect` callback with no dependencies to register it only once - you probably still want to "deregister" it either way, but you wont do it every time `mainList` changes.

Edit: I highly suggest you read the [useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Edit2: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/monojack/ab0c50338ea0a6765467907fe65e7f70)

Comment: where I will put the third code snippet based on your codes sir? I don't understand where should I put it based on your `// ...`

Comment: Is your first code snippet is for my second useEffect snippet or first one?

Comment: Oh its now worknig sir, thank you very much. I don't know but useEffect(), useState(), useReducer(),useRef() is giving a hard time as always but thanks I'll explore much about this!!!

Comment: actually there is one last bug I think..I'm dumb it didn't work properly..where should I put the window.Onscroll() based on your code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/monojack/ab0c50338ea0a6765467907fe65e7f70

Comment: umm maybe try this sir look at my codesandbox so you can briefly more understand it 

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-moon-rvhp4e?file=/src/gallery/Gallery.jsx

sorry for disturbing your time sir..but thank you forhelping me very much... it works but it only call's once but not as I expected to happen.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to see there, `mainList` starts empty and it will never update because it's fetching from `localhost` and that won't work.

Comment: uhh..I'm dead hahhah..I don't know where I should get a help about this ._.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-water-y64qcc?file=/src/gallery/Gallery.jsx
Here try it again sir.. I remove some `.gallery-container` so it could be more understable and just show the `map.function`

Comment: same thing, `mainList` is empty - you are trying to fetch items from `http://localhost:7777/gallery` but this endpoint is only accessible on your machine

Comment: uhhh im really dead hahahhahah but thanks for the hint..I'll find way up for myself thanks.